# Error while loading a shared library when running 'run.sh' in timit/s5 recipe

Tags: kaldi

I am trying to run the kaldi TIMIT/s5 recipe on a remote server. The toolkit is installed and compiled in the server already. The original path where the toolkit is installed and compiled, is a 'read-only' directory where I do not have 'sudo' access to modify anything there. To run the scripts, I have copied the directories for the TIMIT recipe to my local location. I have changed KALDI_ROOT (in 'path.sh') to the original directory where the Kaldi toolkit is installed. When I am trying to run the script 'run.sh', I get the following error :

```
wav-to-duration: error while loading shared libraries: libkaldi-hmm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then, I have added the following line to the end of the 'path.sh' file:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$KALDI_ROOT/src/lib"
```

However, then I get the following error :

```
wav-to-duration: error while loading shared libraries: libfst.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there any suggestions on how to modify the 'path.sh' file so that I could run Kaldi recipes on my local directory?

Thanks for all the answers

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. The error is due to incorrect way setting the root directory for the Kaldi libraries. Moreover, I needed to explicitly point the libraries GCC.8.2.0. The root directories are linked in the 'path.sh' script in the folder of the timit/s5 recipe. Here I share the modified version of my path.sh file that successfully runs the overall run.sh script. Note that the LIBRARY_PATH file should point to your local directory of the shared libraries and the directory for the 'openfst' library (Finite State Transducer Decoding package).

```
export KALDI_ROOT=/import/linux/kaldi
[ -f $KALDI_ROOT/tools/env.sh ] && . $KALDI_ROOT/tools/env.sh
export PATH=$KALDI_ROOT/egs/timit/s5/utils/:$KALDI_ROOT/tools/openfst/bin:$KALDI_ROOT/tools/irstlm/bin/:$PWD:$PATH
[ ! -f $KALDI_ROOT/tools/config/common_path.sh ] && echo >&2 "The standard 
file $KALDI_ROOT/tools/config/common_path.sh is not present -> Exit!" && exit 1
. $KALDI_ROOT/tools/config/common_path.sh

PATH=$PATH:$KALDI_ROOT/tools/openfst
PATH=$PATH:$KALDI_ROOT/src/featbin
PATH=$PATH:$KALDI_ROOT/src/gmmbin
PATH=$PATH:$KALDI_ROOT/src/bin
PATH=$PATH:$KALDI_ROOT//src/nnetbin
export PATH

export LC_ALL=C
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/$KALDI_ROOT/src/lib:$KALDI_ROOT/tools/openfst-1.6.7/lib
```